# How to retrieve JSON objects from ASP.NET Web Form

Tags: asp.net, json

I am passing JSON data to asp.net web form in script. How can I retrieve the id and use in web form

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: 'Edit.aspx',
  cache: false,
  data: ({
    id: id,
    page: lastDirecotry
  }),
  success: function (data) {
    $("#dialog").html(data);
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
  }
});
```

Comment: what is the id here?

Comment: Please add more context and exposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the key piece of information:

```
 type: "GET"
```

Since this is a GET request, the data is going to be query string key/value pairs.  So if this is the data being sent:

```
{ id: id, page: lastDirecotry }
```

Then you can get those values server-side from here:

```
var id = Request.QueryString["id"];
var page = Request.QueryString["page"];
```

Answer (score 0):

in success method you can get data.id to fetch id ,and to fetch page parameter data.page will give you lastDirectory